# iOS - real time live chart that plots data from my sensors in Swift

Tags: ios, iphone-app, charts, real-time, swift

Hey I am building my first iOS/Swift app and I need a free open source or cheap framework for charts. I need a line chart with two datasets and it would be perfect if it would be live/real time. Anyone who has worked with charts/plots in Swift/iOS?